# How can I access class variable inside a NSMutableArray object?

Tags: objective-c

I have "Man" class which also has 2 variable : "description" and "name". At a point, I created Man class and initialize with its own variables (description and name) and pass it to NSMutableArray "collector". How can I access description now ? I tried but ı could not get the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the `Man` object will now be an object in the `collector` array. If so, you would access it like:

```
Man *man = [collector objectAtIndex:42];
NSString *description = [man description];
```

`42` is just an arbitrary index, and `objectAtIndex:` is just one method to access an object in an array (any number of other ways could be used). In the second statement, I've also assumed that you have declared `description` and `name` as properties of the `Man` class, so that they can be accessed from other classes via accessors/mutators (a.k.a getters/setters).